# Issue with logins to SQL Server Windows Authentication to Active Directory Groups

Tags: sql-server, windows-authentication

I have run into a bit of a snag, and unfortunately, I've been unable to locate a concrete answer to my issue. I'll do my best to explain the issue; I hope it makes sense ...

I am having an issue with the way that SQL Server and Windows Authentication works. It's complicated, so I'll do my best to be clear.

For this scenario, picture the following:

- One SQL Server 2008 instance,
- On that server, one database called `Applications`,
- In the `Applications` database there are two schemas called `app1` and `app2`,
- Each schema contains all of the tables for an application of the same name,
- Two Windows AD groups, one for each application, named `app1_RW` and `app2_RW`,
- Any given number of users can be in one, or both, of those AD groups,
- Two .NET applications, both connecting to the database using Windows Authentication mode

  ```
  Data Source=DATABASEINSTANCENAME;Initial Catalog=APPLICATIONS;Integrated Security=True
  ```

When a user opens up either `application1` or `application2`, then the application does the following (in this order):

1. Check to make sure that the current Windows user is a member of the relevent Windows AD group that controls security for that application.
2. If they are a member of that AD group, then allow the application to continue,
3. Log on to the database using Windows Authentication.

**THE PROBLEM**:

When a user is member of both `app1_RW` and `app2_RW`, then it seems that I can't force which group logs on. If the user logs on to `application1`, I'm seeing where the Windows Authentication logs them into the database using `app2_RW`. Therefore, the application fails, because `app2_RW` doesn't have access to the schema / permissions required to run `application1`.

I had hoped that my answer would be as simple as specifying which Windows AD group to log in as in the connection string, but as far as I can find, you can't specify the "User Id" of a connection string if `Integrated Security=True`.

Can anyone offer any help? I very much want to continue using Windows AD groups for administration of my applications. If I've missed any information or if I can clarify, please let me know.

Thank you so much, and have a great day.

Comment: Are you sure you have given complete information? What error message are you getting? Is it a permissions problem or a naming problem? Are both applications in the same catalog or different catalogs?.... Generally what you need to do is create roles in the database, assign the permissions to the roles, then map the logins to database roles using the User Mapping dialog. This will allow you to achieve the many/many mapping you require.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the 2 AD groups are not mutually exclusive you can set rules within the application as to which group is a superset and use that group as logon. If the 2 groups are mutually exclusive again setup a rule to give the minimum permission. Hope that helps.